# How to click on next page by using xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time

url = 'http://dciindia.gov.in/DentistsSearch.aspx?Reg_Type=D&RegUnder=0&IDRId=&IDRName=&CourseId=0&RegDate=0&CouncilId='

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table',{'id':'gvSearchDentistlist'})

next_page = True
while next_page == True:
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table',{'id':'gvSearchDentistlist'})
    try:
        rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            if len(row.find_all('td')) == 6:
                data = row.find_all('td')
                name = data[1].text.strip()
                print("NAME:"+name)
                root_url = data[5].input['onclick'].split(",")[4]
                link ='http://dciindia.gov.in/'+root_url
                print("LINK:"+link)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gvSearchDentistlist"]/tbody/tr[52]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]').click()
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        print ('No more pages')
        next_page=False

driver.close()
```

I am not able to click on the next page. I don't know the end page and there is no 'next' button to click, the pages are given as 1,2,3.. and so on.

Comment: can you help me on this@chitown88

Answer (score 0):

I open the site,
http://dciindia.gov.in/DentistsSearch.aspx?Reg_Type=D&RegUnder=0&IDRId=&IDRName=&CourseId=0&RegDate=0&CouncilId=

and found the page had record the total numbers,

[image: site]

you just need some mathematical. and then get the total page number.

You can used this way to adjust had next page or not?

Comment: yes i can calculate the next page but not able to  click on next page